# Strange phenomenon about the number of threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

My CPU has 2 physical cores, and it supports hyperthreading. Thus, I think I can manage 4 threads. (4 logical cores)
However, using openmp, I can generate much more cores. It is strange.

I'm a newbie in parallel programming, and I learned that there are few ways to set the number of threads I wanna use. I've used two ways below.

1. omp_set_num_threads(4);
2. #pragma omp prarallel num_threads(4);

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(100)
{
    printf("%d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
#pragma omp for
    /* code I wanna parallelize */
}
```

What I think strange is, the logical core number is 4 in my CPU, but why `omp_get_thread_num()` returned 0 to 99. I think it is impossible, what is the meaning of `100` in `#pragma omp parallel num_threads(100)`?

Comment: Threads are not the same as cores.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you for correct my misconception. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have more threads than your cores. Which thread is run to which CPU core is up to the OS (In Windows, you can set the affinity).The OS will run your threads based on its scheduler.

The number of cores is effectively the number of threads that can run *simultaneously*.

If you have two threads that each one takes 1 second and you only have 1 core, then they will finish in approximately 2 seconds, whether if you have 2 cores (and they run in parallel) , they will finish in approx 1 second.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. May I ask one more? Then, is it meaningful that setting the number of threads more than I can run simultaneously?

Comment: It depends. If you have too many threads, they may get at each other and the time needed to switch will be a bottleneck. I usually use exactly the number of cores (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency) The proper way is to benchmark the best for your app.

Comment: It can sometimes be advantageous to have a few more threads than cores. If a running thread gets stuck (waits on a mutex, or waits for I/O), the core has something else to do rather than sitting around doing nothing.